# Easiest way to create a signature fascimile on an Android tablet

Tags: drawing

I would like to create a **fascimile of my signature. Ideally, a high resolution png with a transparent background**.

At my disposal is an Android tablet with a stylus (Samsung Galaxy Tab S9+) and a Linux (Ubuntu) laptop for post-production if necessary. I would prefer to avoid using online services and keep the signature on my devices.

How do I go about it? Starting with the drawing app for Android. If practical, one that is open source and in F-Droid would be best.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have use Samsung Notes for this.

In Samsung Notes you can write your signature using the pen, or if you have a particularly thin finger that might work.

When finished you can tap the 3 dots in the top right and select "Save as file" and then choose PDF. Exporting to PDF keeps high resolution vector graphics so the lines in the PDF will be good and have proper transparency.

Save that PDF to somewhere and email it to yourself.

On a PC install and run [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). Import the PDF you emailed to yourself.

You can trim the file to only the used area  using **File -> Document Properties -> Resize to content** (click the button next to resize)

Then simply save your file. You can use **File -> Export** to get a PNG which will have transparency and be any resolution you like, or you can use **File -> Save as** to export vector formats such as SVG and EMF which have transparency by their very nature.